# C++ understanding issue- linked lists and stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, parentheses

I have to make a code, that checks if parentheses are balanced using **stack** and **linked list**.
Here is my code, that i made using many tutorials and power point presentations from my class, and also with little bit of help from my friend.
but, can anyone explain what is happening under 'int pop' and 'check' parts, line by line(il put as comment parts i do not understand)? I have problems with understanding this part of c++ (stacks and l.lists that are implemented), and i don't have anyone who can explain it and who have time. I've tried many things, but i really don't understand it.
P.S. code works as it should
Thank you guys!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node 
{
   char data;
   node *link;
};

int pop(node *&stack)  //node that points to address of a stack?
{
    char result;
    node *top=new node; //how can i explain this?
    top=stack; //why are we equalizing top with stack?
    result=top->data;//i dont understand
    stack=top->link;//dont understand   
    delete top; 
    return result; 
}

bool Pairs(char openP,char closedP)
{
if(openP == '(' && closedP == ')') return true;
else if(openP == '{' && closedP == '}') return true;
else if(openP == '[' && closedP == ']') return true;
else return false;
}

bool Check(string exp) 
{
   int i=0;
   node *stack=NULL;
    while(exp[i]) 
    {
        if(exp[i]=='(' || exp[i]=='[') 
           {
                node *neww=new stack;//dont understand
                neww->data=exp[i];//dont understand
                neww->link=stack; //-II- 
                stack=neww; //-II-
            }
        if(exp[i]==')' || exp[i]==']')
          {
             if(stack==NULL)
                return 0; 
             else if (Pairs(pop(stack), exp[i])==0) //what does mean this part in parentheses? 
                return 0;                           
          }
        i++;
    }
    if(stack==NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
} 

int main()
{
    string exp;
    cout<<"Enter parentheses:\n";
    cin>>exp;
    if(Check(exp)!=0)
        cout<<"P. are  balanced";
    else 
        cout<<"P. are not balanced";  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and execute it step by step...

Comment: I recommend you to read up about pointers and structs/classes then you'll understand a lot more what's going on. Don't assume that just because you got the code from somewhere else, it's correct. You are right to be suspicious about this code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

- Think about your algorithm ignoring language details. A stack is the right way to go but you don't need to consider how you will implement your stack until you've thought out the algorithm.
- Having decided that you need a given data structure ask yourself whether it already exists in C++ (std::stack) before inventing your own.
- Use C++ idioms not C idioms (i.e. use iterators begin() and end() not indexing) Apart from anything else this will prevent your exp[i] bug.
- Don't have one class doing more than one thing. If you need a stack then create a stack class rather than have your parsing class involved with stack implementations. Firstly it makes it easier to think about the checking algorithm and secondly the stack class can be reused elsewhere.

In outline your solution will use iterators to examine the characters of the string and push and pop opening brackets using a 
**std::stack<char>**. There is no need for **new** or pointers anywhere.

Comment: i've googled some more and found some explanations
i know how to solve this task using only for example bool Pairs and bool CheckIfBalanced, but it's still unclear to me :S is it possible to solve it in any other way? as  i said, we have to use nodes, linked lists and stacks :S

Comment: I don't understand your comment: "we have to use nodes, linked lists and stacks...". Is your task to check for balanced parentheses or to use various unnecessary data structures?